# Communicate from Service to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I start a service in my Activity following way. After the Service started I close the Activity. If I start the Activity again, I want to receive some informations from the service. How can I do that?

```
// Activity

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   // here I want to receive data from Service
}

Intent i=new Intent(this, AppService.class);

i.putExtra(AppService.TIME, spinner_time.getSelectedItemPosition());

startService(i);


// Service

public class AppService extends Service {

  public static final String TIME="TIME";

  int time_loud;

  Notification note;
  Intent i;

  private boolean flag_silencemode = false;


  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    time_loud = intent.getIntExtra(TIME, 0);

    play(time_loud); 

    return(START_NOT_STICKY);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution nowadays, IMHO, is to use a third-party event bus, like [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) (using a `@Producer` to allow the activity to get the last-sent event of a given type) or [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (using a sticky event to allow the activity to get the last-sent event of a given type).

Comment: instead of using third-party solutions, why not simply use **LocalBroadcasts**?

Comment: @Waqas: For event *delivery*, `LocalBroadcastManager` is fine. However, for *pulling* events, there is no equivalent in `LocalBroadcastManager` for Otto's `@Producer` or EventBus' sticky events.

Comment: but what about `context.sendStickyBroadcast`?

Comment: @Waqas: That is not a local broadcast. That involves IPC, plus an extra permission `SEND_STICKY_BROADCAST`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Is there maybe a way to call a function or something from the activity? Because I always have the service running maybe I can access the service from the actifity??

Comment: @user1390816: "Is there maybe a way to call a function or something from the activity?" -- no. "Because I always have the service running" -- no, you do not. First, that is an anti-pattern on Android, and so you really should reconsider doing that. Second, the user can stop your service whenever the user wants, via Settings. Your activity cannot assume that the service exists; the service cannot assume that the activity exists.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library from Square.

> Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your
>   application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

The simple way would be that you create a Bus:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
```

Then you would simply publish an event:

```
bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));
```

to which your `Service` is subscribed

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}
```

and then the service would provide a result

```
@Produce public AnswerAvailableEvent produceAnswer() {
    // Assuming 'lastAnswer' exists.
    return new AnswerAvailableEvent(this.lastAnswer);
}
```